# Dúvida com select em mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom tenho as seguintes tabelas:

Pedidos

```
id      id_cliente      id_vendador
1       10              20
2       10              30
3       10              20
```

Devolucoes

```
Id      data            id_pedido
1       2017/01/01      3
```

Preciso fazer um    ‘select’ informando os ‘id’ da tabela pedidos, e ele tem que me retornar as devoluções que contenham os mesmo clientes dos pedidos.

Exemplo:

```
and id IN(1,2)
```

Ele tem que me retornar o ID 1 da devolução, pois o ‘id_pedido’ dela é 3 e o ‘id_cliente’ é o mesmo do pedido.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Já quebrei a cabeça aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa fazer um `INNER JOIN` na mesma tabela passando o campo que deseja vincular, neste caso o `id_cliente`:

```
SELECT dev.id
  FROM pedidos ped
 INNER JOIN pedidos ped2 ON ped2.id_cliente = pd.id_cliente
 INNER JOIN devolucoes dev ON dev.id_pedido = ped2.id
 WHERE ped.id = [INSIRA AQUI O ID DO PEDIDO]
```

Comment: esta dando esse erro aqui '#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)'

Comment: @HugoBorges Você substituiu o que está entre colchetes pelo id que você quer colocar?

Comment: sim claro neh, coloquei 'ped.id = (1,2)'

Comment: @HugoBorges aí que está seu erro, o operador `=` aceita apenas um argumento, para usar o `(1, 2)` você deve usar o operador `IN`, como você mesmo havia dito na sua sua pergunta: `ped.id IN (1, 2)`

Comment: off e mesmo, erro meu. Deu certo, muito obrigado